# Notify user when there is a very slow internet - Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Need to display "Slow/Bad Signal" when network is slow... How to check if the network is slow ?
I have implemented Network Reachability to check if internet is there or not ...but there is no way to check if the internet is slow or not....

Comment: how do you define "slow"?  A connection to one server might be fast compared to a connection to another server, depending on conditions upstream from the user.

Comment: You could send a request to a server with whatever timeout you want and set your flag based on if it times out. But as Jason said, there's not guarantee that the connection is fast/slow. The server you pinged could simply be overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to describe the rules of slow connection. Usually, it is a timeout in HttpClient. You can setup timeout to your httpClient and catch TimeOutException. But, I would prefer to have a long running background task, checking a host reachability by period of time to detect slow connection even if no any requests are coming